# how to overlap factor(binary) & continuous variables in heat map in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, colors, heatmap

The code below is adapted from https://simplystatistics.org/2019/08/28/you-can-replicate-almost-any-plot-with-ggplot2/

I am trying to overlap the current heatmap for `rate` continuous variable with `Vaccine` factor (binary) variable.

2 questions:

1-Instead of the vertical line, let's say I want to transform the colour of my heat map to be more pink ("palevioletred1") when `Vaccine` ==1 and grey ("gray95") otherwise (`Vaccine`=0).

2-I included `colour = Vaccine` in the gglot to get the bar outline showing pink when Vaccine ==1, but by including it, I saw no difference.

Any ideas on how to do 1 or 2? Thanks in advance.

**Code below:**

```
library(tidyverse)
library(dslabs)

data(us_contagious_diseases)
the_disease <- "Measles"
dat <- us_contagious_diseases %>%
  filter(!state%in%c("Hawaii","Alaska") & disease == the_disease) %>%
  mutate(rate = count / population * 10000 * 52 / weeks_reporting) 

dat1 <- dat

levels(dat1$state) <- c("State1_1","State1_2","State1_3","State1_4","State1_5","State1_6","State1_7","State1_8","State1_9","State1_10",
                        "State1_11","State1_12","State1_13","State1_14","State1_15","State1_16","State1_17","State1_18","State1_19","State1_20",
                        "State1_21","State1_22","State1_23","State1_24","State1_25","State1_26","State1_27","State1_28","State1_29","State1_30",
                        "State1_31","State1_32","State1_33","State1_34","State1_35","State1_36","State1_37","State1_38","State1_39","State1_40",             
                        "State1_41","State1_42","State1_43","State1_44","State1_45","State1_46","State1_47","State1_48","State1_49","State1_50","State1_51")                      

dat2 <- dat

levels(dat2$state) <- c("State2_1","State2_2","State2_3","State2_4","State2_5","State2_6","State2_7","State2_8","State2_9","State2_10",
                        "State2_11","State2_12","State2_13","State2_14","State2_15","State2_16","State2_17","State2_18","State2_19","State2_20",
                        "State2_21","State2_22","State2_23","State2_24","State2_25","State2_26","State2_27","State2_28","State2_29","State2_30",
                        "State2_31","State2_32","State2_33","State2_34","State2_35","State2_36","State2_37","State2_38","State2_39","State2_40",             
                        "State2_41","State2_42","State2_43","State2_44","State2_45","State2_46","State2_47","State2_48","State2_49","State2_50","State2_51")                      

dat3 <- dat

levels(dat3$state) <- c("State3_1","State3_2","State3_3","State3_4","State3_5","State3_6","State3_7","State3_8","State3_9","State3_10",
                        "State3_11","State3_12","State3_13","State3_14","State3_15","State3_16","State3_17","State3_18","State3_19","State3_20",
                        "State3_21","State3_22","State3_23","State3_24","State3_25","State3_26","State3_27","State3_28","State3_29","State3_30",
                        "State3_31","State3_32","State3_33","State3_34","State3_35","State3_36","State3_37","State3_38","State3_39","State3_40",             
                        "State3_41","State3_42","State3_43","State3_44","State3_45","State3_46","State3_47","State3_48","State3_49","State3_50","State3_51")                      

dat4 <- dat

levels(dat4$state) <- c("State4_1","State4_2","State4_3","State4_4","State4_5","State4_6","State4_7","State4_8","State4_9","State4_10",
                        "State4_11","State4_12","State4_13","State4_14","State4_15","State4_16","State4_17","State4_18","State4_19","State4_20",
                        "State4_21","State4_22","State4_23","State4_24","State4_25","State4_26","State4_27","State4_28","State4_29","State4_30",
                        "State4_31","State4_32","State4_33","State4_34","State4_35","State4_36","State4_37","State4_38","State4_39","State4_40",             
                        "State4_41","State4_42","State4_43","State4_44","State4_45","State4_46","State4_47","State4_48","State4_49","State4_50","State4_51")                      

dat5 <- dat

levels(dat5$state) <- c("State5_1","State5_2","State5_3","State5_4","State5_5","State5_6","State5_7","State5_8","State5_9","State5_10",
                        "State5_11","State5_12","State5_13","State5_14","State5_15","State5_16","State5_17","State5_18","State5_19","State5_20",
                        "State5_21","State5_22","State5_23","State5_24","State5_25","State5_26","State5_27","State5_28","State5_29","State5_30",
                        "State5_31","State5_32","State5_33","State5_34","State5_35","State5_36","State5_37","State5_38","State5_39","State5_40",             
                        "State5_41","State5_42","State5_43","State5_44","State5_45","State5_46","State5_47","State5_48","State5_49","State5_50","State5_51")                      

dat <- rbind(dat,dat1,dat2,dat3,dat4,dat5)
dat$Vaccine <- 0

dat$Vaccine[dat$year >= 1963] <- 1
dat$Vaccine <- as.factor(dat$Vaccine)

jet.colors <- colorRampPalette(c("#F0FFFF", "cyan", "#007FFF", "yellow", "#FFBF00", "orange", "red", "#7F0000"), bias = 2.25)
    
dat %>% mutate(state = reorder(state, desc(state))) %>%
  ggplot(aes(year, state, fill = rate, colour= Vaccine)) +
  geom_tile(color = "white", size = 0.35) +
  scale_x_continuous(expand = c(0,0)) +
  scale_fill_gradientn(colors = jet.colors(16), na.value = 'white') +
  geom_vline(xintercept = 1963, col = "black") +
  theme_minimal() + 
  theme(panel.grid = element_blank()) +
  coord_cartesian(clip = 'off') +
  ggtitle(the_disease) +
  ylab("") +
  xlab("") +  
  theme(legend.position = "bottom", text = element_text(size = 8)) + 
  annotate(geom = "text", x = 1963, y = 50.5, label = "Vaccine introduced", size = 3, hjust = 0)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Option 1**

Use `annotate` to add a transluscent rectangle.

```r
dat %>% mutate(state = reorder(state, desc(state))) %>%
  ggplot(aes(year, state, fill = rate)) +
  geom_tile(color = "white", size = 0.35) +
  annotate("rect", xmin = 1963, xmax = Inf, ymin = -Inf, ymax = Inf,
           alpha = 0.2, fill = "palevioletred1") +
  scale_x_continuous(expand = c(0,0)) +
  scale_fill_gradientn(colors = jet.colors(16), na.value = 'white') +
  geom_vline(xintercept = 1963, col = "black") +
  theme_minimal() + 
  theme(panel.grid = element_blank()) +
  coord_cartesian(clip = 'off') +
  ggtitle(the_disease) +
  ylab("") +
  xlab("") +  
  theme(legend.position = "bottom", text = element_text(size = 8)) + 
  annotate(geom = "text", x = 1963, y = 50.5, 
           label = "Vaccine introduced", size = 3, hjust = 0)
```

[image]

**Option 2**

You can use `scale_color_manual`. Just ensure your `Vaccine` column is genuinely a factor variable with levels `"0"` and `"1"`

```r
dat %>% mutate(state = reorder(state, desc(state))) %>%
  ggplot(aes(year, state, fill = rate)) +
  geom_tile(aes(color = Vaccine), size = 0.35) +
  scale_color_manual(values = c('0' = "white", '1' = "pink")) +
  scale_x_continuous(expand = c(0,0)) +
  scale_fill_gradientn(colors = jet.colors(16), na.value = 'white') +
  geom_vline(xintercept = 1963, col = "black") +
  theme_minimal() + 
  theme(panel.grid = element_blank()) +
  coord_cartesian(clip = 'off') +
  ggtitle(the_disease) +
  ylab("") +
  xlab("") +  
  theme(legend.position = "bottom", text = element_text(size = 8)) + 
  annotate(geom = "text", x = 1963, y = 50.5, label = "Vaccine introduced", 
           size = 3, hjust = 0) +
  guides(color = guide_legend(override.aes = list(fill = "white")))
```

[image]

For what it's worth, I prefer option 1

---

**Update**

If you want multiple vaccine starting points you can do this too:

```r
dat %>% mutate(state = reorder(state, desc(state))) %>%
  ggplot(aes(year, state, fill = rate)) +
  geom_tile(color = "white", size = 0.35) +
  annotate("rect", xmin = 1963, xmax = Inf, ymin = 25, ymax = 50,
           alpha = 0.2, fill = "palevioletred1") +
  annotate("rect", xmin = 1975, xmax = Inf, ymax = 25, ymin= 0,
           alpha = 0.2, fill = "palevioletred1") +
  scale_x_continuous(expand = c(0,0)) +
  scale_fill_gradientn(colors = jet.colors(16), na.value = 'white') +
  theme_minimal() + 
  theme(panel.grid = element_blank()) +
  coord_cartesian(clip = 'off') +
  ggtitle(the_disease) +
  ylab("") +
  xlab("") +  
  theme(legend.position = "bottom", text = element_text(size = 8)) + 
  annotate(geom = "text", x = 1963, y = 50.5, 
           label = "Vaccine introduced", size = 3, hjust = 0)
```

[image]

Comment: This is excellent, thanks Allan. I would prefer option 1 as well but in my case the "vaccine" was introduced at different years for different states, so I cannot create such transluscent rectangle as per your code in option 1. Do you know how to change the legend name for each variable and how to make inside white instead of grey for binary variable?

Comment: @DanielaRodrigues you _could_ still use rectangles. I'll update to show how.

Comment: Many thanks Allan, will explore option 1 with your update. Re option 2, do you know how to prevent the binary variable to be filled in grey instead of white?